# how to read xml data from website and display the same in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, json, xml-parsing

I know how to make JSON data and use it in displaying json data in UITableView. Sample JSON data is at link http://www.sama-q8.com/sama/getBuildingInfoSama.php

For the new project, client have provided XML data. Sample data is at

http://sahhtna.hardtask.org/services/mobileservice.asmx/Clients?type=1&index=0

I want to learn how to get this data in NSArray format (like I do using json data).

I tried searching some links, but didn't get good links. Any good links by someone would be great.

I was looking at [this example](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/) and I think this is not what I was expecting.

But I am really confused in the format of XML data that I have at link http://sahhtna.hardtask.org/services/mobileservice.asmx/Clients?type=1&index=0

Text "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." in webpage is fine or it will give me problem while parsing the XML data?

Also the format that I have in above link is right or not?

Please let me know.

Comment: You won't get any problem from the text: "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." That is just something your browser is showing you when you look at raw XML data.If you view source on that page you will see it's just plain XML.

Comment: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking + http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Comment: @barn.gumbl : just curious, afnetworking for what? i never used it before... and I think you gave me perfect links...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you are trying to do. An XML file is the same as an RSS Feed. Infact an RSS Feed is simply an XML file.

There is a class called NSXML Parser which allows you to parse through the xml file, and load the elements into a dictionary.

This is a perfect example, if you download this project http://media.theappleblog.com/downloads/TAB_RSS_reader.zip

Have a look at the source code and you will understand how an XML file is parsed and put into a table view.